# Problema con Remove en java

Tags: java, arraylist

tengo un problema con un programa que me pide registro, búsqueda y bajas. El problema está con las bajas, que me tira muchos errores. Adjunto el código de las bajas:

```
case 5:
                System.out.println("Ingresa ID de auto a dar de baja: ");
                int idbaja = entrada.nextInt();
                System.out.println("Eliminando...");
                for (Automoviles autom : autos) {
                    if (autom.getId() == idbaja) {
                        int indice = autos.indexOf(autos);
                        autos.remove(indice);
                    }
                }
                break;
```

Answer (score 1):

[indexOf()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#indexOf-java.lang.Object-) Devuelve el índice de la primera aparición del elemento especificado en esta lista,pero tu le estas pasando como parametro la lista

```
int indice = autos.indexOf(autos);
```

lo que debes pasarle como parámetro es el objeto que cumple con la condicional

```
int indice = autos.indexOf(autom);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! Eres el mejor!